# Meteor error 416: Error serving static file Error: Requested Range Not Satisfiable

Tags: javascript, meteor

Error on Meteor Server:

(webapp_server.js:457) Error serving static file Error: Requested Range Not Satisfiable

This error occurs on the server whenever I try to get id3 tags from .mp3 files, using [this library](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader). The problem is not caused by the library, as it is only doing it the second time the id3 tags are requested.

```
    id3({
        file: src
    }, function(err, tags) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(tags);
            if (tags.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
                $('.title').text('Title: ' + tags.title);
            }
            if (tags.hasOwnProperty('album')) {
                $('.album').text('Album: ' + tags.album);
            }
            if (tags.hasOwnProperty('artist')) {
                $('.artist').text('Artist: ' + tags.artist);
            }
            if (tags.hasOwnProperty('year')) {
                $('.year').text('Year: ' + tags.year);
            }
            if (tags.hasOwnProperty('genre')) {
                $('.genre').text('Genre: ' + tags.v1.genre);
            }
            if (tags.v2.hasOwnProperty('image')) {
                $('.image').html(tags.v2.image.data);
            }
        } else {
            alertify.error(err);
        }
    });
```

The src variable looks like:

```
var src = 'songs/' + title + '.mp3';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to caching on the client side. Can you clear/disable browser cache? Here's an explanation of [HTTP 416](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/http-status-codes/)

Comment: Ok. I disabled browser caching and it works fine. I don't want other clients to have to do the same though.

Comment: You're probably have to change from GET to POST then. POST are never cached on the client.